# Want to show same record from multiple tables at the same time (Oracle Live SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause

I have three separate tables for a USA, Asia and Europe stock market. The only stock that is in all 3 of them is Apple in my scenario. The code below works..

```
Select * from USA_Stock 
Where Name='Apple (AAPL)'
```

But I want it to show all three at the same time, but when I try this

```
Select * from USA_Stock, Europe_Stock, ASIA_Stock 
Where Name='Apple (AAPL)';
```

it gives me the following error

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: You need to give alias to the table and it should work ..but your join is incorrect .. you are doing cross join without giving any condition and it will certainly create lot of rows..try using inner join, left join ..it will be much more clear

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax

Comment: I'd consider to have one common Stock table, for all regions.

Comment: Got it. Yeah I made 1 at the beginning but am required to make 1 per each stock market.

Comment: Always reassuring to see students forced to implement bad practice to get a passing grade.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know that Apple is the only share present in all three tables, and you just want to show the Apple records from each table, then perhaps a union is more along the lines of what you need:

```
SELECT name, price FROM USA_Stock WHERE name = 'Apple (AAPL)'
UNION ALL
SELECT name, price FROM Europe_Stock WHERE name = 'Apple (AAPL)'
UNION ALL
SELECT name, price FROM ASIA_Stock WHERE name = 'Apple (AAPL)';
```

Comment: Thanks, so I just use the 'UNION ALL' code whenever I am calling a duplicate item, right?

Comment: One more question. I tried the max command but I want it to show the whole row rather than just the price. This is the code I used: SELECT MAX(Buy_Price) FROM USA_Stock;

Comment: "so I just use the 'UNION ALL' code whenever I am calling a duplicate item, right?"  No,  you use it in situations where it is appropriate.  This is one of those situations.  Some other situation that may _seem_ similar may, in fact, be better solved by some other query.  These are not the kinds of things where you can say "I should always ....".  Experience will be your best teacher, but only if you keep yourself open to alternative solutions.  When your only tool is a hammer, all problems look like nails.

Comment: @EdStevens - sometimes it seems like everyone wants a silver bullet when what they need is a lead pencil.

Comment: I once worked for a contracting house that also had a product sales business, and one day we got the two-hour dog-and-pony show for their new be-all-and-end-all development tool. I thought, "This is never going anywhere - it's a bad VB re-hash". One of my less-motivated colleagues said, "So once we learn this we never have to learn anything else? Sweet!!!". Of course, product never went anywhere - local product office never sold one copy. Last I knew my former colleague was baby-sitting paycheck printing for a third-party HR provider. Guess he never learned anything else. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, price FROM USA_Stock WHERE name = 'Apple (AAPL)'
INTERSECT
SELECT name, price FROM Europe_Stock WHERE name = 'Apple (AAPL)'
INTERSECT
SELECT name, price FROM ASIA_Stock WHERE name = 'Apple (AAPL)';
```

returns only lines which have  the same name

Comment: This will return **one row**, which I don't think is what the Seeker wants, and only returns that if the `price` is the same in all three tables.